# passing arguments to function in the imported module from console

Tags: python, function, arguments

I have a simple script

```
import os
os.system('cls')
def addition (a , b ):
    """
    Learning Python to make a better world
    This is my first program
    """
    c = a+b
    print (c)

addition(3,8)
```

How can I pass the arguments to the function **addition** from the console after its imported ?

I am sure this is very basic question but somehow I am struggling with this.

Comment: What did you try?  How did you import it?

Comment: @BrenBarn , So when I import the script as follows:
>>>import myfirst (myfirst is .py script) I get the result 11

How can i pass arguments to the function from console , I know my script needs modification but not sure what it is

Comment: Once you import it, just do `myfirst.addition(1, 1)`, or whatever numbers you want.

Comment: @BrenBarn Bingo ! Exactly what I was looking for , using the same piece of script I was able to pass different arguments right after the import. Great answer !

Answer (score 2):

If you use sys instead of os, you can do

```
import sys
a = int(sys.argv[1])
b = int(sys.argv[2])
addition(a,b)
```

where you would call the script using a command like

```
python addition.py 1 2
```

where addition.py is the name of your script.

Comment: I tried changing my script to as you said but I get this 
import sys
a = sys.argv[1]
b = sys.argv[2]
def addition (a , b ):
    """
    Learning Python to make a better world
    This is my first program
    """
    c = a+b
    print (c)

python myfirst.py 2 4
  File "<input>", line 1
    python myfirst.py 2 4
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: The code runs on my machine - I don't see anything in the line import sys that should cause a syntax error. Indentation and whitespace are important in python. Each statement must be on its own line.

Comment: Also, usually you should define your functions right after your import statement, and before you make any other statements or call any functions - just to keep things organized.

Comment: The script is all properly indented , you thin you can paste your script here and how you calling it on the console ?

Comment: My script looks exactly my posted code, but with the function definition in between the import statement and everything else. As for how I'm calling it, that is also in the answer.

Comment: @JacobRitchie I have changed the script as per your recommendation but seems like I am making some silly mistake somewhere

Comment: You are putting my command inside the python interpreter. The 'console'  I am talking about is something like Terminal on Linux or Command Prompt on Windows.

Comment: To call a function from inside the interpreter, you can just write `addition(3,8)`.

Answer (score 0):

Modified the addition function as class structure:

```
Class Add:    
  def __init__(a,b):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b

  def addition (self):
    """
    Learning Python to make a better world
    This is my first program
    """
    c = self.a+slef.b
    print (c)

 if __name__ == '__main__':
   add1 = Add(sys.argv[1:])
   Add.addition()
```